# Not able to get the filenames of uploaded files in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, upload

I have followed Multiple file upload with Symfony2 and created a entity

```
/*
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\attachmentsRepository")
 */

class attachments
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     * @ORM\Column(name="files", type="array", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $files=array();

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set files
     * @param object $files
     * 
     * @return attachments
     */
    public function setFiles($files) {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    /**
     * Get files
     *
     * @return object 
     */
    public function getFiles() {
        return $this->files;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $files = array();
    }

     public function uploadFiles() {
        // the files property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->files) {
            return;
        } 

        if (!$this->id) {
                $this->files->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->files->getClientOriginalName());

        } else {
            $this->files->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->files->getClientOriginalName());
        }

        $this->setFiles($this->files->getClientOriginalName());
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath() {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath() {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/'. $this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir() {
        return 'uploads/';
    }

}
```

I have a controller which has the folowing code

```
class uploadController extends Controller
{

    public function uploadAction(Request $request) {

        $id= $_GET['id'];

        $user = new attachments();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)->add('files','file',array("attr"=>array("multiple" =>"multiple",)))->getForm();

        $formView = $form->createView();

        $formView->getChild('files')->set('full_name','form[file][]');

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $form->bind($request);
            $files = $form["files"]->getFilenames();
            $user->uploadFiles(); //--here iam not able to get te file names in order to send to the upload function.upload files is returning null values

       }
   }
}
```

the controller is not able to get the filenames that is uploded by the uder from the view.it is returning null values when i send to the upload function in entity

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, could you provide more info besides code?

Comment: i want to upload the multiple files.For that i need to get the filenames that have uploded by the user from the view to the controller when i try to retrive the uploaded files from the controller using form["files"]->getData();it is returning null values

Comment: when i pass the  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); in the upload function it is returning null values i.e it is not able to take the filenames from the controller to the entity inorder to upload.in the controller itself it is not able to get the filenames from the view

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the [Documentation about File Upload](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) again. You are correctly using the annotation `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` but your code is missing the right annotations for the methods. You can use the `@ORM\PostPersist()` and `@ORM\PostUpdate()` annotations to call the `upload()` function automatically after the request was validated and the object was persisted. Also I would suggest using an entity for each file and creating a [OneToMany](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany) relation. This will make it more easy and logical to store your files correctly.